# Rails - upsert no unique index found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is my migration file.

```
  def change
    add_index :book_owners, [:book_id, :book_detail_id], unique: true, where: 'book_id IS NOT NULL and book_detail_id IS NOT NULL'
  end
```

This is my code.

```
BookOwners.upsert({
  book_id: 123,
  book_detail_id: 234,
  ...
}, unique_by: { columns: [:book_id, :book_detail_id] })
```

But I am getting this error.

```
No unique index found for {:columns=>[:book_id, :book_detail_id]}
```

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL or Sqlite3, right?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs:

> Unique indexes can be identified by columns or name:
>
> unique_by: :isbn 
>   unique_by: %i[ author_id name ] 
>   unique_by: :index_books_on_isbn

I see you're passing a hash to the `unique_by` option, try using just the array `[:book_id, :book_detail_id]`:

```
BookOwners.upsert({
  book_id: 123,
  book_detail_id: 234,
  ...
}, unique_by: [:book_id, :book_detail_id])
```